# Atom editor looks like html inspector?

Tags: atom-editor

I was fiddling around with the .atom folder on my Mac and moved it around but I deleted it (thinking it would reset things!) and it made the editor turn into this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [atom.io](https://discuss.atom.io/uploads/github_atom/original/3X/d/4/d42d7343e418ed439ada52073c4ef7e61741b45f.png))</sub>

I think it is a html inspector kinda like the one in safari?
No amount of installing and reinstalling could fix this. I deleted the frameworks, the .atom folder and anything to do with is so why is it stuffing up? I may have to change to [Brackets](http://brackets.io) if this an't be fixed…

Is there a way to do a fresh install?

Please help I don't like Brackets!

Comment: Try hitting option+command+i. This is the developer tools for Electron.

Comment: @Matt Ok, now it is just a blank window. I think it isn't installing the files it should. Why would this be happening if I am installing it new and there are no files already existing?

Answer (score 0):

.atom is a folder that have all data which your atom need to run e.g : packages that you may download will be save there. Be sure , it doesn't effect your browser inspector.